# ByteBuffer put method adds 0 after ByteArray

Tags: java, put, bytebuffer

I currently ran into a actually quite weird problem with the put method of java.nio.bytebuffer and I wondered if you might know the answer to it, so let's get to it.

My goal is it to concatenate some data to a bytebuffer. The problem is after I call the put method it always adds a 0 after the byte array.

Here is the method which has those side effects:

```
    public ByteBuffer toByteBuffer() {

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024));
    
    buffer.put(type.name().getBytes()); // 0 added here

    data.forEach((key, value) -> {
        buffer.putChar('|');
        buffer.put(key.getBytes()); // 0 added here
        buffer.putChar('=');
        buffer.put(value.getBytes()); // 0 added here
    });

    buffer.flip();

    return buffer;
}
```

Expected Output should look something like this:

```
ClientData|OAT=14.9926405|FQRIGHT=39.689075|.....
```

Actual Ouptut where _ represents the 0s:

```
ClientData_|OAT_=14.9926405_|FQRIGHT_=39.689075_|.....
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about this side effect.
Also the put method only puts a 0 in between the byte arrays but not at the very end of the buffer.

I assume the method might be wrong or at least not properly documented, but I really have no clue why it would behave that way.

Comment: No it doesn't. Already checked if the getBytes() method might be the cause of the problem.

I used        
 byte[] tmp = type.name().getBytes();
and it returned an array containing the according letters, e.g. "ClientRequest" and is not null terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be slightly misinterpreting what is happening here. I note your comment about "but not at the very end of the buffer".

The `\0` is actually coming from the `putChar(char)` calls, not the `put(byte[])` calls. As it says in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putChar(char)) (emphasis added):

> Writes **two** bytes containing the given char value, in the current byte order

The default byte order is big endian; given that the chars you are writing are in the 7-bit ASCII range, this means "the byte you want" is going to be preceded by `0x00`.

If you want to write a byte, use `put(byte)`:

```
buffer.put((byte) '|');
```

Comment: The background is that Java uses UTF-16 for the representation of characters. For one character 2 bytes are used

Comment: Thanks! I completely missinterpreted the wireshark data because it looked like the \0 was added after the put. Thanks a lot! That was actually quite simple.